# Understanding R function lazy evaluation

Tags: r, function, namespaces, lazy-evaluation

I'm having a little trouble understanding why, in R, the two functions below, `functionGen1` and `functionGen2` behave differently. Both functions attempt to return another function which simply prints the number passed as an argument to the function generator.

In the first instance the generated functions fail as `a` is no longer present in the global environment, but I don't understand why it needs to be. I would've thought it was passed as an argument, and is replaced with `aNumber` in the namespace of the generator function, and the printing function.

My question is: Why do the functions in the list `list.of.functions1` no longer work when `a` is not defined in the global environment? (And why does this work for the case of `list.of.functions2` and even `list.of.functions1b`)?

```
functionGen1 <- function(aNumber) {
  printNumber <- function() {
    print(aNumber)
  }
  return(printNumber)
}

functionGen2 <- function(aNumber) {
  thisNumber <- aNumber
  printNumber <- function() {
    print(thisNumber)
  }
  return(printNumber)
}

list.of.functions1 <- list.of.functions2 <- list()
for (a in 1:2) {
  list.of.functions1[[a]] <- functionGen1(a)
  list.of.functions2[[a]] <- functionGen2(a)
}

rm(a)

# Throws an error "Error in print(aNumber) : object 'a' not found"
list.of.functions1[[1]]()

# Prints 1
list.of.functions2[[1]]()
# Prints 2
list.of.functions2[[2]]()

# However this produces a list of functions which work
list.of.functions1b <- lapply(c(1:2), functionGen1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more minimal example:

```
functionGen1 <- function(aNumber) {
  printNumber <- function() {
    print(aNumber)
  }
  return(printNumber)
}

a <- 1
myfun <- functionGen1(a)
rm(a)
myfun()
#Error in print(aNumber) : object 'a' not found
```

Your question is not about namespaces (that's a concept related to packages), but about variable scoping and lazy evaluation.

Lazy evaluation means that function arguments are only evaluated when they are needed. Until you call `myfun` it is not necessary to evaluate `aNumber = a`. But since `a` has been removed then, this evaluation fails.

The usual solution is to force evaluation explicitly as you do with your `functionGen2` or, e.g.,

```
functionGen1 <- function(aNumber) {
  force(aNumber)
  printNumber <- function() {
    print(aNumber)
  }
  return(printNumber)
}

a <- 1
myfun <- functionGen1(a)
rm(a)
myfun()
#[1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Will accept answer and change title of question to mention lazy evaluation. This was tripping me up and now know what to search for.

Comment: If you don't know the term, you should also look up "closures" since that's what you are creating there.