# Understanding lazy evaluation in R

Tags: r, function, haskell, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to understand just how lazy evaluation in R works. Does it only apply to the evaluation of function arguments? Because that I understand, e.g.

```
f <- function(x = x, y = x*2) {
  c(x, y)
}

f(2)
[1] 2 4
```

But in other languages, e.g. Haskell, lazy evaluation means that a function call only gets evaluated if it's ever actually used. So I would expect something like this to run in an instant:

```
g <- function(x) {
  y <- sample(1:100000000)
  return(x)
}

g(4)
```

But it clearly evaluates the `sample` call even though its result doesn't get used.

Could somebody explain exactly how this works, or point me in the direction of where it is explained in detail?

Similar questions:

[Question with similar wording, but different problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361844/understanding-r-function-lazy-evaluation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you already have found out, R does not use lazy evaluation in the general sense. But R does provides that functionality, if you need it, by the function `delayedAssign()`as shown below:

```
> system.time(y <- sample(1E8))
   user  system elapsed 
  7.636   0.128   7.766 
> system.time(length(y))
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
system.time(delayedAssign("x", sample(1E8)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.000   0.000   0.001 
> system.time(length(x))
   user  system elapsed 
  7.680   0.096   7.777
```

As you can see, `y` is evaluated immediately, so to determine the length of `y` takes no time at all. `x` on the other hand, is not evaluated when it is created, only a promise to evaluate `x` is returned by `delayedAssign()`, and only when we actually need a value of `x`, in this case to determine its length, `x` is evaluated.

It does not matter if the expression is placed in a function or executed in the global enviroment, so the encapsulation of the expression within a function which you did in your example, does not really add anything, which is why I excluded it. But if you want to be sure, try:

```
a.f <- function(z) { delayedAssign("x", sample(1E8)); return(z+1) }
system.time(a.f(0))
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0
```

Comment: I am referring to Hadley Wickham's book, where he mentions :

" By default, R function arguments are lazy, they are only evaluated, if used actually". Is it not true with the latest versions then ?

Comment: Note that the question included this phrase "Does it only apply to the evaluation of function arguments?" My answer does not contradict Wickham's statement.